# The solution is executed with error 'out of bounds' on the line 7

Tags: c++, c++17

I have received this *bound error* though the sample input and output match. I tried several ways to solve this error, but I couldn't. Please help me to overcome this problem. And also please, explain why? what is the main reason for this error?. My code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[4];
    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i]=='1'){
            sum=sum+a[1];
        }
        else if(s[i]=='2'){
            sum+=a[2];
        }
        else if(s[i]=='3'){
            sum+=a[3];
        }
        else if(s[i]=='4'){
            sum+=a[4];
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Sample input:

```
1 2 3 4
123214
```

Output:

```
13
```

Comment: **cin >> a[i];** on this line, it shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes start at `0` so `a[4]` is out of bounds in your case.\

Since we're here I recommend to not use C arrays. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Also it's better to use the [range for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not correct

```
int a[4];
for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

arrays in C++ are indexed from 0, so it should be if you want to have `a[1] = 1`

```
int a[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

*Side note. You dont need the "look-up array". To sum numbers, you can just do:*

```
sum += (s[i] - '0');
```

Comment: as you mentioned, `sum += (s[i] - '0');` I would like to know, how this line will work.

Comment: Look up ASCII table and check numbers - all chars representing numbers are placed one after another in order 0,1,...9. So the difference between them and '0' is equal to the actual number they represent.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[4];
    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
```

The variable declaration for `a` allocates indices 0 to 3 (4 elements total), yet you're trying to access 0 to 4 via `i`

Comment: I think you have a typo. The OP is trying to access indices 1 to 4.